# Spring Boot JPA many to many jackson, serialize each entity

Tags: java, jpa, jackson

I have two entities, User and Role; they have many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_authorities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Authority> authorities;

}
```

I want to serialize both entities to JSON, so that when I'm going to get users I could see their Role's, but Role object itself should not have a User's Collection

```
[
  {
    id: "624a174b-0a9e-49be-9116-2b0b2aee4014",
    username: "admin",
    password: "$2a$12$Neo1AdkqDWa2fTeLsAn7T.t9S4/70zDE7Ab2sCPVJ9wy18qNdESpW",
    email: "admin@gmail.com",
    roles: [
      {
        id: "613bb9f1-1607-4f8d-8cd2-f08217d60829",
        name: "ROLE_USER",
      },
      {
        id: "8ed0f60b-71e5-427f-a485-7bdec5a64768",
        name: "ROLE_ADMIN",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "1825d4f7-d655-4b7e-aefb-e9e82d316c59",
    username: "string",
    password: "$2a$10$C.lyzjlv/d5CpsZw.5IxUOD08UzhCjOzeOfcsPC.Ua.SHvvej6SV2",
    email: "string@mail.ci",
    roles: [
      {
        id: "613bb9f1-1607-4f8d-8cd2-f08217d60829",
        name: "ROLE_USER",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and so for Role's

```
[
  {
    id: "613bb9f1-1607-4f8d-8cd2-f08217d60829",
    name: "ROLE_USER",
    users: [
      {
        id: "624a174b-0a9e-49be-9116-2b0b2aee4014",
        username: "admin",
        password: "$2a$12$Neo1AdkqDWa2fTeLsAn7T.t9S4/70zDE7Ab2sCPVJ9wy18qNdESpW",
        email: "admin@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        id: "1825d4f7-d655-4b7e-aefb-e9e82d316c59",
        username: "string",
        password: "$2a$10$C.lyzjlv/d5CpsZw.5IxUOD08UzhCjOzeOfcsPC.Ua.SHvvej6SV2",
        email: "string@mail.ci",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "8ed0f60b-71e5-427f-a485-7bdec5a64768",
    name: "ROLE_ADMIN",
    users: [
      {
        id: "624a174b-0a9e-49be-9116-2b0b2aee4014",
        username: "admin",
        password: "$2a$12$Neo1AdkqDWa2fTeLsAn7T.t9S4/70zDE7Ab2sCPVJ9wy18qNdESpW",
        email: "admin@gmail.com",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Now I can achieve this only partially by adding @JsonIgnore either to Collection of roles in User class or to Collection of users in Role class

I'm looking for something like conditional @JsonIgnore, so that I could for example add appropriate annotation on corresponding REST Controller

How can I do this?

Comment: Please describe what the final 2 code blocks are:  Are they output; and if so, under what condition?

Comment: Do NOT use the database entities to either represent the requests or responses. Use separate DTOs. In a DDD-design, both `User` and `Role` would be aggregate roots. I would strongly advice to only reference other aggregate roots by their id only (see [this question over at softwareengineering.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/328571/324190)).

Comment: You can create a flat object, that extends User or create an interface that `User` and `FlatUser` can implement, where the `Flat*` classes only encapsulate part of the properties.

Comment: Another option is to use a concept of [projection](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate-projection-example.html#:~:text=Hibernate%20Projection%20is%20used%20to,set%20ProjectionList%20object%20to%20Criteria.), where your hibernate entity manager can recognise both `User` and `FlatUser` as the same table, and project only fields that are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark all attributes that you don't want it to be parsed with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation

Please check my post [here](https://sw-academia.blogspot.com/2015/11/gson-stackoverflowerror.html), It should contain guidance to your question, however it was using `GSON` not `Jackson`

Comment: Please read: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For REST controllers separate [DTO classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) can be defined.
Serializing DB Entities with Jackson could work, but having immutable [DTO classes describing the API contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/august/pros-and-cons-of-data-transfer-objects) is more common and makes REST API specifics less coupled from the database implementation.

If your controller is responding with serialized DB entities like here:

```
public Iterable<User> getUsers() {
  return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

It can instead map those entities into DTOs that are designed specifically for this response:

```
public List<UserDto> getUserDtos() {
  var users = userRepository.findAll();
  var userDtos = StreamSupport.stream(users.spliterator(), false)
    .map(u -> new UserDto(u))
    .collect(toList());
  return userDtos;
}
```

Where DTO classes could look like:

```
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public UserDto(User user) {
        this.setId(user.getId());
        this.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        this.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        this.setRoles(
          user.getRoles()
            .stream()
            .map(r -> new RoleDto(r))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }
}
```

And

```
@Data
public class RoleDto {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    public RoleDto(Role role) {
        this.setId(role.getId());
        this.setName(role.getName());
    }
}
```

Classes above utilize constructors to instantiate DTO objects from their DB entities. This code can be extracted to mapper classes to avoid changing DTO (which may be a part of the REST API contract) every time a database column is renamed. Mapper classes could be auto-generated using tools like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).